# Asp.Net WebApi - Post a file

Tags: c#, rest, file, post, asp.net-web-api

Can anyone give me some light about this problem? I've been trying to post a file and some parameters to an WebApi, but using multipart/form-data didn't work at all. What can i do? Here's the code from:

-Client-

```
public string Put(string appkey, string senha)
    {
        string url = $"{"http://localhost:59701"}/api/Ocr";
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1);
        string xml = "";


        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

            using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var values = new[]
                {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key", "awesome"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("From", "khalid@home.com")
             //other values
        };

                foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
                {
                    multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value),
                        String.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));
                }

                multipartFormDataContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(Arquivo), '"' + "File" + '"', NomeArquivo);

                var result = client.PutAsync(url, multipartFormDataContent).Result;
            }
        }

        return xml;
    }
```

-WebApi-

```
public class OcrController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public void Extrair(CourierMessage input)
    {
        //do anything
    }
}

public class CourierMessage
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Processed { get; set; }
    public DateTime Received { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Sent { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to bind every property to an object just like we do in MVC?